# Change url of page according to my requirements in wordpress

Tags: permalinks, redirect

I am facing problem with change permalink actually I am using Redirection plugin you can see this plugin from here.

```
   http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/
```

I have installed this plugin and activate.After that I want to change the url of page having page id 5 .Url is provided for each page by client so I need this

```
  for example:page_id=5 is about us page and I want to change this as shown in target URL

  Source URL:http://www.lifecellskin.us/Dev/?page_id=5
  Target URL:http://www.lifecellskin.us/Dev/About.php
```

After that I clicked Add Redirection But when I click About us tab from header navigation it navigate to `About.php` but show this message give below.

You have entered the wrong url/ page name. Click here for continueCLICK HERE

Please help me its very urgent.Please provide me any help regard this how this plugin will work in right way as I want

Thanks

Comment: Does it have to be `About.php`, or is `about` also good? The latter case would just require you to enable ["pretty permalinks"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks), for which you don't need a plugin. I'm not sure, but I don't think the Redirection plugin will do what you want here: you want the URL to stay the same, and I think the plugin forwards you to another page. Is it OK if request to `/About.php` are redirected to `/about`? This way old links still work, and new ones use the built-in WordPress structure.

Comment: My problem is only that I just want to redirect` http://www.lifecellskin.us/Dev/?page_id=5
` to target url 'URL:http://www.lifecellskin.us/Dev/About.php`.I don't want the /about   or /about.php.I exactly need /About.php.Because SEO  is done for this website

Answer (score 1):

Are both ?page_id=5 and About.php same page? If yes:

1. First go to Settings > Permalinks > Permalink Settings and change the Common settings to anything other than the default.
2. Once configure use this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-to-pages/ or any other that's similar.

Make sure the Page slug is edited according to your liking. You can edit the page slug individually from Pages > Pages.

Comment: Ya page slug editable but when I try to enter`About ` and click ok button  its change to `about`.Thanks for reply.Any suggestion

Comment: For reference: @shalu asked a follow-up question to know [how to allow upper-case letters in slugs](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/how-can-i-make-capital-letter-upper-case-permalinks).

Comment: Forgot about slug and lowercase. +1 at Jan Fabry solution there.