# Import Wordpress Post Slug with Forward Slash

Tags: redirect, slug

Building a news site in Wordpress. Importing articles from old, custom-built site. I want the imported URLs to be the same, to preserve SEO equity. The URLs should look like:

**site.com/category/article-slug/2409230** (legacy id# at the end)

So each *Post's* full slug would be like **article-slug/2409230** (with forward slash in the middle).

- Using **Custom Permalinks** plugin which lets me have forward slash ('/') in slug when editing an individual article.
- Using **WP-All-Import** plugin to manage the import process, all data & slug fields are normalized and ready to go.
- Updated **sanitize_title_with_dashes** function (described [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/5032)) to allow forward slash ('/') in slug when importing.

Upon importing old articles, it's saving the slug as intended. Displays intended URL when I hover on *View* link, and checked the **wp_posts** 
DB entry to verify.

**The problem is** when I open that post, it does the following:

**site.com/category/article-slug/2409230** 301 redirect to

**site.com/category/article-slug/2409230/2409230** which is a 404

If I *Edit* an imported post, update the slug, *Save*, revert slug, and *Save* again - it works properly (**Custom Permalinks** plugin is doing its job here). But I can't do that 27k times for all of these old articles.

Anyone know what's making Wordpress want to redirect the imported slugs? Or how I can avoid this and get the imported articles to load without manually editing each one?