# How to prevent wordpress from lowering Capitalized letters

Tags: permalinks, slug

I have the same issue as discussed here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384768/how-can-i-make-capital-letter-upper-case-permalinks/4386225

I made changes to formatting.php like said above. But it allows to save the permalink/slug only at the very begining of the creation of the page/post. When I update the page (or try to change the slug)  WP lowers the Capitalized slugs. I need to have the ability to save/change/update with Uppercase letters. It seems there is a JS - onblur code, which lowers the letters.
Any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: “I made changes to formatting.php”. _Never_ do this. That is a bad answer and should be ignored. You should revert any changes you have already made.

Comment: See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/how-can-i-make-capital-letter-upper-case-permalinks#answer-5032 for a filter which is safe to use, as opposed to modifying any Core files.

Comment: @WebElaine, the filter you mentioned only allows to save the permalink/slug at the very begining of the creation of the page/post. When the page is updated those Capitalized (which were saved as Capitals when the page was created) letters get lowered by wordpress.